# trying to use query_posts('category_name=page_slug');

Tags: php, wordpress

I´m trying to query posts after category name and want the ('category_name=*cat-name*');  *cat-name* to be taken from the page title, lets say the page title is "Forename Lastname" then the perma-link will be /forename-lastname/ . Is it possible to make the *cat-name* copy the "forname-lastname" with php or must I try to make some a javascript to take care of it?

Comment: https://tommcfarlin.com/get-permalink-by-slug/  Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you, it looks just right, i just don´t understand how to apply it to ('category_name=cat-name')where "cat-name" is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "permalink" of the page it's stored as its `post_name`, so you can get it from the global `$post`

For instance:

```
global $post;
$slug = $post->post_name;
$posts_in_cat = query_posts('category_name='. $slug );
```

Comment: Thank you! that was exactly what i´ve been trying to do